# What does "Field theory limit" means in D/M-branes or supergravity theories?

Tags: string-theory, branes, supergravity

What does "Field theory limit" means in D/M-branes or supergravity theories?

Reading some papers related with D/M-branes, they often mention field theory limit,  $i.e$, limit of $\alpha\rightarrow 0$, what does this means in detail? 
Is it related with $Ads/CFT$ which related gravity with field theory?

Comment: could you give some references to the papers you are reading?

Comment: You can find some relevant sentence in [9903003](http://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/9903003.pdf), maldecana's paper on [9711200](https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/9711200v3.pdf), [0007018](http://cds.cern.ch/record/445802/files/0007018.pdf) and some textbook like Johnson's D-brane. or [article](http://www.rug.nl/research/portal/files/3125223/c5.pdf)

Comment: The introduction to the Skenderis paper clearly states: *"Taking the field theory limit, **i. e. the limit in which bulk gravity decouples**"* [emphasis mine]. What exactly is unclear to you?

Comment: @ACuriousMind, I want to understand the relation of bulk gravity decouples and  limit of string tension, $\alpha \rightarrow 0$.  In what sense ,I mean, How one can decouple bulk gravity?

Comment: Comment to the title (v1): Supergravity is already a field theory. No limit is needed.